# Best way of accumulating large amounts of Candy Corn in GW2

Tags: guild-wars-2

The new Blood and Madness season has begun in GW2.

New items have become available from the TP. These items range in price from 1 - 12 Candy Corn Cobs.

The only way I know to get 1 Candy Corn Cob, is by combining 1,000 pieces of Candy Corn.

I know three methods of getting Candy Corn:

1. Mining Candy Corn nodes around Tyria, each one producing maybe 10 pieces of Candy Corn if you're lucky.
2. Buying them on the TP. I haven't done the math but I'm sure buying 12,000 pieces would be pretty expensive.
3. Retrieving them from [Trick or Treat bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Trick-or-Treat_Bag) which are pretty common drops during the Blood and Madness season. (But only 1-12 in each bag)

Are there any other ways of gathering large amounts of Candy Corn?

**UPDATE**

I have found [this handy farm guide](http://www.almarsguides.com/gw2/GettingStarted/Halloween/candycorn/), but I'm hoping there is another way. Reward from events or instances perhaps?

(Maybe this is just lazy / wishful thinking on my part)

Comment: Buying a Candy Corn mining node for you home instance will give you a steady supply of candy corn you can mine each day.

Comment: @DavidYell Already have one :) Picked that up last year as a reward for something I think.

Comment: Having the node in your home instance is enough to get maybe 2 to 5 cobs a year. It's very, very slow in comparison to the Halloween event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the fastest method of getting Candy Corns is getting large amounts of [Trick-or-Treat Bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Trick-or-Treat_Bag) from the [Mad King's Realm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mad_King%27s_Labyrinth) with a zerg. Run around the Labyrinth with a zerg and open the [Haunted Doors](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Haunted_Door) while simultaneously mining the nearby Candy Corn Veins. Personally, I was able to get over 1000 Candy Corns in about 2 hours on the first night of the holiday while leading the zerg.

There are three types of events that start when opening doors:

- **Boss event**: Spawns one of the champion bosses
- **Veteran event**: Spawns a veteran enemy and potentially some normal enemies as reinforcements
- **Normal event**: Spawns a large amount of normal enemies

The normal events can give you the largest amount of Trick-or-Treat Bags if you are able to tag the majority of the enemies. They all have very low health and spawn at approximately the same location, so tagging them is going to require the use of constant cleave attacks on their spawn point.

Note that the type of door (**Mad King Door** or **Bloody Prince Door**) doesn't have any effect on whether or not a door will spawn a boss event, veteran event, or normal event. It does have an effect on which enemies the door can spawn, though.

## Boss Events

Boss events can only be spawned from one specific door. Their exact locations are marked on the GW2 wiki page of their bosses. If you are interested in only getting bags, it may be in your best interest to navigate the zerg away from these doors, entirely. However, they are achievement-related, so people will want to do them at least once before the holiday is over.

- **Mad King Door** can spawn a [Legendary Skeletal Lich](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Legendary_Skeletal_Lich).
- **Bloody Prince Door** can spawn a [Grand High Viscount of Candy Corn](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Grand_High_Viscount_of_Candy_Corn).

## Veteran Events

These events go by much quicker than Boss Events, but since they are so easy, I recommend also killing nearby enemies after you've tagged the Veteran.

#### Mad King Door

- Candy Corn Elemental
- Gargoyle
- Glow-in-the-Dark Spider
- King-Sized Candy Corn Elemental
- Plastic Spider

#### Bloody Prince Door

- Mummy
- Skeleton
- Rebel Lunatic

## Normal Events

These are the events that you are most interested in, as you'll get the most kills and the most loot.

#### Mad King Door

- Bite-Sized Candy Corn Elemental
- Candy Corn Elemental
- Gargoyle
- Glow-in-the-Dark Skeleton
- Glow-in-the-Dark Spider
- Plastic Spider
- Small Plastic Spider

#### Bloody Prince Door

- Mummy
- Rebel Lunatic
- Skeleton

Comment: Ran the MKL for a few hours over the wkend and was able to gather around 6 thousand pieces of candy corn. Honestly now I think I'm going to have too many! :D